# How to control output bit depth in graphicsmagick (for Node)?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, iojs

So I have two PNG images, both non-transparent 24bpp.
One image contains a rainbow, other one contains a single line of text:
[image]

I do the same thing with both of them:

```
var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true})
gm("./sources/source.png").bitdepth(24).write("test.png", function(){
    console.log("test.png")
});
gm("./sources/source2.png").bitdepth(24).write("test2.png", function(){
    console.log("test2.png")
});
```

where `gm` is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm)

And I set both to 24bpp [explicitly](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#bitdepth)

In result I have two images with different bit depth:

[image]

In some cases I also had 32bpp image.

How can I make it create only 24bpp image (discard alpha channel if needed).
Also, I don't want to create jpgs.

---

Thanks to [@mark-setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/), I could force bit depth. I did it this way in Node:

```
gm("./sources/source.png")
    .out("-define")
    .out("png:color-type=2")
    .write("test.png", function(){
    console.log("test.png")
});
```

`out()` is an undocumented method but it basically helps you add custom parameters to commandline. Notice that

```
    .out("-define png:color-type=2")
```

won't work, it only works if you pass each parameter in individual `.out()` call

`.bitdepth(24)` doesn't seem to affect output at all, **probably** because I did `.subClass({imageMagick: true})` above.

Comment: Try adding `+matte` to your command, or prefixing your output filename with `PNG24:`, i.e. `PNG24:test2.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried, it made "rainbow" image output 32bpp, but "line of  text" image remained 8bpp

Comment: Can you provide your input images as they are, rather than mixed up in combined images please?

Comment: Can you maybe force `png:color-type=2` to be defined, using `-define`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell `-define png:color-type=2` worked, thanks! You, probably, should post it as an anwer for visibility

Comment: Glad it worked out for you and thank you for sharing the technique.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to try using `-define` to set the variable `png:color-type=2`. As you worked out, and kindly shared with the community, it is done as follows:

```
gm("./sources/source.png")
    .out("-define")
    .out("png:color-type=2")
    .write("test.png", function(){
    console.log("test.png")
});
```